How to prevent ListPicker from highlighting all items initially in WL?
I'm using the ListPicker function within an Input dialog in Wolfram Language to allow users to select one item of a list. However, I've encountered an issue where all the items in the ListPicker appear highlighted in blue initially, which I would like to avoid.

Here's a simplified version of my code:
   Input[Text[Style["Pick one of the obtained equilibria", 16]], 
   DynamicModule[{sol = {
      {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 0}, {x1 -> (d α)/(c - d), 
      x2 -> (r α (c - d - d α))/(c - d)^2}, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0}}, 
   parpicker = {}}, {ListPicker[Dynamic[parpicker], sol], 
   Dynamic[parpicker]}]]

When the dialog appears, all items in the ListPicker are highlighted in blue until I click on an item with the cursor.
Is there a way to modify this behavior so that no items are highlighted initially when the dialog appears? I would prefer the items to appear without any selection or highlighting by default.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

You shouldn't be using Input for this. Use DialogInput instead, for example:
DynamicModule[{sol = {{x1 -> 1, 
     x2 -> 0}, {x1 -> (d  α)/(c - d), 
     x2 -> (r  α  (c - d - d  α))/(c - d)^2}, {x1 -> 0, 
     x2 -> 0}}, parpicker = {}},
 DialogInput[DialogNotebook[{
    TextCell@"Pick one of the obtained equilibria",
    ListPicker[Dynamic[parpicker], sol], Dynamic[parpicker],
    Row[{CancelButton[DialogReturn[False]], 
      DefaultButton[DialogReturn[parpicker]]}]}]]
 ]


Hello, @Domen! I extend my sincere thanks for your detailed and insightful response to my recent question. I just learned a lot from this approach you used, it solves my problem perfectly.
